# JAVA Data Overwrite error

Tags: java

I have an assignment to write a program to project your annual fuel usage based on three fill ups of a car. I have to use two separate classes. This is my first class, titled AnnualFuelUse.

```
public class AnnualFuelUse
{
    private static int endMiles, startMiles,fillUp, days,distance;
    private double gallonsUsed, pricePerGallon,MPG,cost;


    AnnualFuelUse(int fu, int d, int sm, int em, double gu, double price)
    {
        fillUp = 0;
        days = d;
        startMiles = sm;
        endMiles = em;
        gallonsUsed = gu;
        pricePerGallon = price;
        distance = 0;
        MPG = 0.0;
        cost = 0.0;
    }

    public void calcDistance ()
    {
        distance = endMiles - startMiles;
    }

    public int getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }

    //calculates miles per gallon
    public void calcMPG()
    {
        MPG =  distance /gallonsUsed;
    }

    public double returnMPG(){
        return MPG;
    }

    public void totalCost(){
        cost= gallonsUsed * pricePerGallon;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
    public int returnStart(){
        return startMiles;
    }
    public int returnEnd(){
        return endMiles;
    }
    public int returnDays(){
        return days;
    }
    public double returnGallons(){
        return gallonsUsed;
    }
    public double returnPrice(){
        return pricePerGallon;
    }
}
```

This is my second class, titled AnnualFuelUseTester. (sorry for the long names, but it's required)

```
public class AnnualFuelUseTester
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

    AnnualFuelUse[]fuel = {new AnnualFuelUse(1,1,45023,45231,10.00,2.95),
                           new AnnualFuelUse(2,4,45231,45480,11.70,2.99),
                           new AnnualFuelUse(3,8,45480,45659,9.30,3.01),
                           new AnnualFuelUse(4,13,45659,45961,14.90,3.01)};                                    
    for (int index = 0; index<fuel.length;index++)
    {
        fuel[index].calcDistance();
        fuel[index].calcMPG();
        fuel[index].totalCost();
    }

    System.out.println(" Fill Up  Days   Start Miles   End Miles   Distance   Gallons Used   MPG   Price   Cost   ");;
    for(int index = 0; index < fuel.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%5d %6d %9d %12d %12d %10.2f %13.1f %6.2f %6.2f \n",
        index+1,fuel[index].returnDays(),fuel[index].returnStart(),fuel[index].returnEnd(),fuel[index].getDistance(),fuel[index].returnGallons(),fuel[index].returnMPG(),fuel[index].returnPrice(),fuel[index].getCost());
    }
```

My problem is that when I run the program, the days, start miles, end miles, and distance columns all have the same numbers in them, the data for the last fill up. The gallons used, MPG, Price, Cost, all work fine. So in the Days Column, instead of reading 1, 4, 8, 13, it reads 13, 13, 13, 13.

I would appreciate some help in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields should not be static. That means one per class (not instance)

```
private static int endMiles, startMiles,fillUp, days,distance;
```

should be

```
private int endMiles, startMiles,fillUp, days,distance;
```